# How to access a function inside another function

Tags: javascript

How do I call the inner function from outside in the following code ?

```
(function (){
    var funOne = {
        funTwo : function (){
            var funFour = function(){
                console.log('inner function working');
            }
        },
        funThree : function () {
            console.log('working');
        }
    }
    funOne.funTwo(); // works
    funOne.funThree(); // works again
    funOne.funTwo.funFour(); // throwing exception

    })();
```

Comment: You should give `funOne` a different name - it is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scoping issue with funFour compounded by trying to define funTwo act as a function (`funOne.funTwo()`) and an object (`funOne.funTwo.funFour()`).

Here are 2 options to get access to funFour:

1. Let funTwo make funFour accessible at the more accessible level (for example, via funOne).
2. Have funTwo return funFour within an object. You still have to add the parenthesis to actually call `funTwo()` in your output.

How to change funTwo:

```
    funTwo : function (){
        var funFour = function(){
            console.log('inner function working');
        };
        funOne.funFour = funFour; // Option 1
        return { 'funFour': funFour }; // Option 2
    },
```

How to call each option:

```
funOne.funFour(); // Option 1
funOne.funTwo().funFour(); // Option 2
```

Comment: Option 2 is working well. However I could not run the option 1.

Comment: Here's the JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/3qy07s0d/) showing both options in a full example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access **Local variable** (var funFour) of **function funTwo** from outside. If you want to use **funFour** at outside of function funTwo, you need to declare funFour as **Global variable**.

Edited code is here.

```
(function (){
    var funFour;
    var funOne = {
        funTwo : function (){
            funFour = function(){
                console.log('inner function working');
            }
        },
        funThree : function () {
            console.log('working');
        }
    }
    funOne.funTwo(); // works
    funOne.funThree(); // works again
    funFour(); // Call function funFour here

    })();
```